# Laravel get all from with belongTo value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel 8 project I have two tables A and B:

```
| A     |
---------
| ID    |
| B_ID  |
| VALUE |


| B       |
-----------
| ID      |
| VALUE   |
| Private |
```

In my models I have:

```
A{
    public function b()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(B::class);
    }
}

B{
    public function as()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(A::class);
    }
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
public function index()
{
    $a = A::join('bs', 'as.b_id', '=', 'b.id')->get(['as.value', 'bs.value']);

    return $a;
}
```

Is'nt there a more elegant Laravel way to do this?
I would like to get all records from table A with the value from table B but without the private value from B. (There could be a lot of entries in Table A, Table B only has some values (<20) ).

Answer (score 0):

When building a query, you may specify which relationships should be eager loaded using the with method. In your case you could write:

```
A::with('b:value')->('value')
```

In the with you can precise a specific relationship by its name or a list of column you want : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

The code I have provided as an example as not been tested and may need some changes but you have the general idea